# Allow only external links in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using `TinyMCE` in my webapplication, and allowing people to use `link` in it.
This is my config:

```
        var editor = tinymce.init({
        plugins: "link",
        selector: this.$el.find("#shortdesc")["selector"],
        toolbar: "bold italic | undo redo | link unlink",
        link_list: [
        ],
        menubar: false,
        relative_urls: false,
        link_assume_external_targets: true,
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on("change", function (e) {})
        }
    });
```

The issue I'm trying to solve is that I want let people insert only **external links**. In the current situation, when the user click on the `link` button and confirm, it shows this popup

[image]

My goal is to avoid showing this popup and use only `http://` prefixed links.

I'm using the last version of `tinyMCE`.

As far as I could understand `relative_urls` options does not fit my necessities.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I solved overriding the `tinymce.editor.convertURL` `function`

```
             setup: function (editor) {
                var fn = editor.convertURL;
                editor.convertURL = convertURL_;
                function convertURL_(url, name, elm){
                    fn.apply(this, arguments);
                    console.log(arguments);
                    var regex = new RegExp("(http:|https:)?\/\/");
                    if (!regex.test(url)) {
                        return url = "http://" + url
                    }
                    return url;
                }
             }
```

Comment: While overriding `convertURL` is a good start, the dialog asking me to prepend "http" still pops up (pressing any button will happily end up in a url starting with "http".

Answer (score 1):

Based on an answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381771/6224185), I wrote the following compact solution for your problem:

```
editor.on('init',function(e) {

    // reference to original windowManager function
    var fn = editor.windowManager.open;

    // override with your own version of the function
    editor.windowManager.open = function(t,r){

        // make sure you only target the 'insert link' dialog
        if(t.title == 'Insert link'){

            // reference to the subumit function of the dialog
            var oldsubmit = t.onSubmit;

            // override the submit function
            t.onSubmit = function(e){

                // append the "http://" prefix here, note that the URL is contained within the property 'href' of data. 
                // also see link/plugin.js
                if(!e.data.href.match(/(ftp|https?):\/\//i)){
                    e.data.href = "http://" + e.data.href;
                }

                // submit original function
                return oldsubmit(e);
            }

            // after overwriting the submit function within the windowManager, make sure to call the original function
            fn.apply(this, [t,r]);
        }

        // use return instead of apply to prevent bugs in other dialogs
        else{
            return fn(t,r);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the link plugin, rename it to something like "mylink", adjust all references to link to mylink and modify the code so that the popup will not show up and the link url is checked for "https"/"http",

Comment: Oh, I get it. I thought there was a way less "hacky"